# React-hook-form errors are not updating

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm building a form with custom components, and I can't get the errors object to be updated when there's an invalid field, I can get the onInvalid callback to run when the password is invalid, but not when the email is invalid. How can I fix these errors?

App.tsx

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import SectionTitle from "./components/SectionTitle";
import EmailInput from "./components/inputs/EmailInput";
import PasswordInput from "./components/inputs/PasswordInput";
import PrimaryButton from "./components/PrimaryButton";

import { useForm, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form";

export interface LoginInputs extends FieldValues {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<LoginInputs>({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    }
  });
  const onSubmit = (data: Record<string, any>) => console.log("submit", data);
  const onInvalid = (errors: Record<string, any>) =>
    console.log("invalid", errors);
  const emailValue = watch("email");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("errors", errors);
  }, []);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onInvalid)}
      className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full p-8 lg:max-w-[500px] gap-6 m-auto"
    >
      <SectionTitle title="Login" />
      <EmailInput
        placeholder="Email address"
        id="email"
        email={emailValue}
        resetEmail={() => {
          setValue("email", "");
        }}
        register={register}
        validationHandlers={{
          required: true
        }}
        errors={errors}
      />
      <PasswordInput
        placeholder="Password"
        id="password"
        register={register}
        validationHandlers={{
          required: true,
          minLength: 8
        }}
        errors={errors}
      />
      <PrimaryButton text="Log In" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here I have a demo https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-nightingale-7c5ice?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1712

Answer (score 0):

Add `noValidate` to your form component to skip the default browser validation:

```
<form
    noValidate
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onInvalid)}
    className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full p-8 lg:max-w-[500px] gap-6 m-auto"
>
```